# Qual a finalidade da função free()?

Tags: c, c++, gerenciamento-de-memória

- Em quais casos deve ser utilizado?
- Existe alternativa?
- É recomendável usar?

Comment: Se seu sistema aloca memória dinamicamente (como 99,99% dos programas o fazem) então é necessário liberá-la quando a mesma não for mais necessária. Mas sempre é possível se programar usando somente variáveis estaticamente alocadas... Não estou dizendo que é uma boa ideia, mas pode haver casos em que esse é o melhor caminho. Só de curiosidade, eu já vi um sistema *bastante* complexo desenvolvido dessa forma - por ignorância em vez de por escolha, sim, mas ele cumpriu satisfatoriamente seu propósito.

Comment: Eu sou do tempo que não existia *heap* e não precisava liberar memória :) Nem *stack* tinha. O código pré-alocava toda memória necessária antes da execução. Você apenas fazia pequenos *jobs* que executavam apenas uma tarefa, não tinha função. nem existia sistema operacional, só um programa monitor. Bem, quando comecei já estava mais moderno mas cheguei fazer coisa antiga assim.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Até um tempo atrás o Objetive C também tinha gerenciamento manual de memória, neste caso não havia como fugir você tinha que alocar cada objeto, reter e liberar cada referência de cada ponteiro, para evitar memory leaks e null pointers access. Hoje temos o ARC, contudo em alguns casos algumas empresas ainda optam por não usa-lo (mais para suporte a código legado) visto que ativa-lo sem remover todos os allocs e retain e release iria dar erro de copilação. As vezes é uma questão de necessidade ou de convenção da empresa.

Comment: @ooredroxoo Não entendi a relação entre o que você falou e meu comentário (se é que era pra ter relação... :P). O que eu quis dizer é que se não há alocação dinâmica, não há liberação dinâmica. Pessoalmente, acho perfeitamente possível conceber um programa simples - que "faz uma só coisa e a faz bem" - que possa operar com memória fixa. Tudo ia depender do propósito do programa e dos tipos de dados que ele manipula. De novo, não é o mais usual, só levantei uma possibilidade...

Comment: @mgibsonbr apenas comentei para exemplificar alguns casos onde nem sempre podemos escapar da alocação manual de memória (bem como sua liberação), embora cada vez mais tenhamos métodos de gerenciamento automático de memória que facilitam nossas vidas.

Comment: Alguma resposta resolveu a questão? Você consegue aceitar alguma?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## O que é

É a função para *desalocar* memória alocada no [*heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101) (lá explica porque o *heap* é necessário). Ela costuma ser usada em par (não necessariamente de forma direta) com [`malloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc).

## Recomendação

Em códigos além do trivial não tem como evitar o uso do `malloc()` (e suas irmãs [`calloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) e [`realloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc), portanto não dá para evitar o uso do [`free()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free).

Onde usa o `malloc()` tem que usar o `free()`. Claro que em coisas **muito** simples pode não usar. Está errado, mas não causará problemas. Mesmo em coisas simples é hábito do bom programador fazer sempre correto.

Então você deve usar sempre. Não tem como escapar dela a não ser que queira comprometer toda memória do computador. Imagine que você vai alocando memória e vai sempre deixando lá. Se a aplicação executa por algum tempo e faz alguma coisa útil em bem pouco tempo muitos gigabytes de memória serão pouco para sua aplicação. Um programa gera muito lixo (dados que foram necessários em um momento, mas não são mais).

#### Quando usar

Uma das recomendações é usar as duas funções em conjunto dentro da mesma função para evitar se perder e esquecer de desalocar, ou pior ainda, desalocar o que ainda não pode e ainda será usado pela aplicação.

Claro que nem sempre isso é possível. Aí o cuidado precisa ser redobrado. Documentação, cautela e muito teste serão necessários.

Em C++ isso fica ainda mais complicado porque mesmo que esteja na mesma função, no mesmo escopo uma exceção pode ser lançada e desviar o fluxo do programa sem você saber, e uma chamada à função `free()` ou uso do operador `delete` pode não ser executado, como seria esperado. Daí um gerenciamento um pouco mais automático passa ser fundamental.

## Alternativas

A alternativa é usar um gerenciamento automático. No fundo este gerenciamento usará o `free()` de alguma forma já que esta função é usada para se comunicar com a API do sistema operacional para liberar a memória.

#### *Garbage collector*

Em alguns casos esse gerenciamento automático pode ser um [*garbage collector*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) mas não costuma ser usado em C/C++ já que a linguagem não ajuda. Além disto ele costuma mudar as características do uso da linguagem indo contra a cultura delas.

#### Delete

Em C++ até existe alternativa. Na verdade, é recomendado usar o [`delete`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_%28C%2B%2B%29) (que internamente acaba usando o `free()` mas de uma forma mais organizada) e não o `free()` .

Na verdade, em C++ o `free()` deve ser evitado em favor do operador `delete` ou mesmo `delete[]` que desaloca *arrays*. A função original do C é muito bruta para os padrões do C++. Ela ainda pode ser usada, já que precisa de compatibilidade com C, precisa se comunicar com o SO e em alguns casos uma flexibilidade maior pode ser necessária (bem raro).

#### Smart pointers

Mais ainda, é recomendado deixar o gerenciamento semiautomático usando classes próprias para controlar o gerenciamento da memória. Estas classes fazem a alocação e sabem quando precisam *desalocar* deixando o programador livre desta decisão. Estas classes são chamadas de [*smart pointers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer). Elas ajudam muito, mas não fazem milagres. Se você esquecer de usá-los ou usar o a classe errada para isto poderá obter resultados indesejados.

#### Outra linguagem

Se não quer cuidar do gerenciamento da memória a alternativa é usar uma linguagem com memória gerenciada, como é mais comum hoje em dia. C/C++ devem ser usadas quando você precisa do poder, flexibilidade e velocidade dessas linguagens. Muitas vezes a escolha de uma delas é justamente para poder gerenciar a memória como quiser.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: +10 pelo último paragrafo.

Comment: Em C++ Se Não Usar delete A Memória Não É Liberada ? E Em C Também Não ?

Comment: Durante a execução da aplicação ela não é liberada até você mandar. Esta é a vantagem destas linguagens, você controla como quer usar a memória.

Comment: @bigown Mas Depois Que Fecha É Liberada Né ?

Comment: Sim. Está no meu comentário na outra resposta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43766/qual-a-finalidade-da-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-free/43770#comment87093_43769

Answer (score 17):

A função [`void free(void *ptr)`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_free.htm) serve para libertar memória alocada anteriormente pelas funções [`calloc`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_calloc.htm), [`malloc`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm), ou [`realloc`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_realloc.htm).

Deve ser utilizada em todos os casos em que já não seja necessário o uso dum espaço de memória anteriormente alocado.

Eu diria que é *obrigatório* usar. Não no sentido de não funcionar, mas no sentido de manter a integridade da sua memória.

Na linguagem C os acessos à memória são de extrema importância, caso não tenhamos essa preocupação vai dar asneira pela certa.

**Nota:** *Tenha sempre em atenção a alocação de memória para que não aloque menos memória do que a necessária para o que pretende. E tenha sempre o cuidado redobrado de libertar o espaço de memória que já não precise.*

Comment: Adicionando um caso de experiência própria:
Eu tinha perto de 50% da RAM usada antes de começar a usar memória alocada dinamicamente com C. Não usava free pra liberar a memória. Depois de alguns usos, a memória do PC estava com 80% de uso, pois não era liberada quando os programas fechavam.

Comment: @mutley: Quando um programa fecha o sistema operacional pega de volta toda a memória que ele estava usando, independente de o programa ter dado free ou não. O problema maior é quando você tem um programa que roda em background, sem fechar.

Comment: No caso de linguagens com `garbage collector` como Java, sim. mas C/C++ não tem isso. O gerenciamento de memória do programa fica totalmente a cargo do desenvolvedor. Se você faz um `int x;`, realmente o programa libera a memória dessa variável quando termina. Mas se você faz algo como `char *p = malloc(valorAqui);` essa memória **DEVE** ser liberada no fluxo do programa, caso contrário, a memória alocada vai ficar ali até que o sistema seja reiniciado.

Comment: @mutley isto está errado, a memória do *heap* será liberada no fim da execução do programa também, sempre. Uma das funções do sistema operacional é justamente controlar seus processos. Quando o processo acaba e a memória alocada por ele obviamente não é mais necessária é automaticamente liberada pelo SO. Não faria nenhum sentido mantê-la. Entenda que é o SO que controla o uso da memória e não sua aplicação. O SO dá permissão para sua aplicação usar porções da memória e ele pode tirar quando ele quiser (claro que ele não o faz aleatoriamente).

Comment: Então, nesse caso que eu falei, o SO estava associando a memória alocada não liberada a nada? Ou ele iria liberar caso fosse necessário?

Comment: Não estava, esses 80% estavam relacionados a outras coisas. Quando a aplicação fecha, a memória é liberada imediatamente. No máximo o que pode ter acontecido é a aplicação não ter sido fechada e você não percebeu. É impossível a memória estar alocada à nada.