# Uso correto do free() em função

Tags: c, ponteiro, alocação, gerenciamento-de-memória, funções

Como usar função `free()` quando ela é usada dentro de uma função? Nesta função gero um vetor dinâmico e o próprio será o retorno da função, exemplo:

```
int* copia(int *vet, int tam)
{
    int i, *retorno;
    retorno = (int*) malloc(tam * sizeof(int));
    
    for(i = 0; i < tam; i ++)
        retorno[i] = vet[i];
    return retorno;
};
```

A minha dúvida é como liberar o vetor `retorno` corretamente, pois o Dev não aponta erro, seria assim?

```
return retorno;
free(retorno);
```

Na *teoria* você sempre tem de liberar um ponteiro alocado dinamicamente e ele deve ser liberado quando acaba o seu uso, mas o `return` geralmente é usado para finalizar uma função, logo eu fiquei intrigado com isso, pois se eu colocar o `free` depois do `return` quer dizer que ele não liberou o meu vetor?

Porque na *teoria*, depois de `return` a função para de rodar, logo ele não leria o `free` embaixo dele, mas também não posso colocar o `free` antes do `return`, porque ainda estou usando o vetor na linha `return`.

Qual é o jeito correto?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O jeito mais correto é não fazer dessa forma. Em C, o ideal é sempre alocar e liberar a memória na mesma função. Então parece que está certo, mas a alocação deve ser feita no menor nível onde ela será usada.

Se for insistir em alocar nessa função, não vai causar nenhum problema diretamente. Mas a função terá que documentar que aquela alocação deverá ser liberada e terá que confiar que isso seja feito. Dessa forma fica assimétrico, já que a liberação não poderá ser feita nela, afinal, se liberar, não pode retornar algo que está sendo destruído.

```
int* copia(int *vet, int tam) {
    int *retorno = malloc(tam * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++) retorno[i] = vet[i];
    return retorno; //está retornando porque será usado fora daqui
}
```

Chamada:

```
int *novo = copia(vet, tam);
//faz alguma coisa com o novo
free(novo); //aqui acaba o seu uso
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/3AX4Hz). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/kmjafuqg-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/Free.c).

Se seguir a recomendação para manter o código mais organizado, será mais ou menos assim:

```
void copia(int *vet, int tam, int *retorno) {
    for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++) retorno[i] = vet[i];
}
```

Chamada:

```
int *novo = malloc(tam * sizeof(int)); //aqui aloca o que esta função precisa usar
copia(vet, tam, novo); //não precisa retornar porque já passou por referência
//faz alguma coisa com o novo
free(novo); //aqui acaba o seu uso
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/UuIzW0). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hkepvfxp-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/Free2.c).

A regra básica é que cada função deve ser responsável por tudo o que ela precisa. Se ela precisa de um dado alocado, ela deve alocar. Se ela alocou, ela deve liberar. Fica mais fácil controlar assim e evitar vazamento de memória, certo?

Leia [mais sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43766/101).

Na pergunta se fala em Dev. Seria o Dev C++? Se for, recomendo usar [outro compilador/IDE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/101703/101). Este é bem problemático e deixa passar muita coisa errada, pelo menos por padrão. Ele é feito para facilitar, mas também incentiva aprender errado.

Comment: Obrigado por tirar a dúvida! Sim, é o Dev C++, sei que ele é problemático, mas como na faculdade ele é o único instalado eu aderi ele para fazer os trabalhos, lembrei de um dia numa prova, printando `8 + 2` ele printava  que era `20`.. Vou dar uma olhada no link, tenho instalado o Code::Blocks, porém o compilador dele não está funcionando, vou dar uma pesquisada sobre o erro e passar a usa-lo ou olhar os outros do link.