# Por que ainda consigo acessar uma variavel na heap mesmo depois da funçao terminar?

Tags: c++, funções, ponteiro, stack, heap

Faz um tempo q apreendi sobre *heap* e *stack*, estava testando alguns códigos quando me deparei com um comportamento estranho na *heap* veja;

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Test1(int *i[]);
void Test2(int *i);

int main() 
{
    int *p[10];// declara um vetor ponterio para 10 inteiros
    int num_ = 10; //criar um interio com o nome num_ de valor 10 na heap

    p[0] = &num_; //passa o endereço de num_ para a primeira posiçao do vetor de ponteiros inteiros
    cout<< *p[0]<<endl; // mostra p[0] primeiro valor da primeira posiçao do vetor de ponteiros
    Test1(p);// chama a funçao Test1 q receber um vetor de ponteiros no paramentos
    cout<< *p[0]<<"**"<<endl; // o valor agr é 47, pq ?

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /*int *p_;
    int num__ = 10;
    p_ = &num__;
    cout<< *p_<<endl;
    soma_(p_);
    cout<< *p_<<endl;*/

    return 0;
}

void Test1(int *i[])
{
    int p = 47; //criar um inteiro na heap com valor 47
    i[0] = &p;/*passa o emdereço do interio "p" criado na heap para o vetor de interios*/
    /* no caso a variavel "p" foi criado na heap quando
     * essa funçao termina o "p" devia ser apagado assim p *i[0] agr nao devia aponta para luga nemhum,
     * mas quando sai da funçao Test1 o valor ainda esta acessivel no p[0] da main
     *  */
}

void Test2(int *i)
{
    int p = 47;
    i = &p;
}
```

Por que ainda posso acessar o valor 47 da variável `int p` da função test1, se o valor foi para *heap* e quando a função termina o valor `p` deveria ser apagado? Pelo que eu entendi sobre variáveis na *heap*, as variáveis são apagadas quando a função termina.

Comment: Não tem nada no *heap*, então a pergunta parte de algo bem errado.

Comment: mas na função test1(int *p[]) ha uma variavel int p = 47 ,onde ela esta se não na heap?

Comment: No Stack.......

Comment: ctz pq vi em alguns site que uma variável dentro de uma função esta sempre na heap, so esta no stack se usasse o operador new para criar

Comment: Nunca mais volte para este local que ensina errado. Ao que parece é exatamente o oposto.

Comment: não não desculpe eu que confundir a heap seria a memoria maior q usa o operdor new para alocar ne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em nenhum mo momento este código faz uso do *heap*, então a confusão do que está acontecendo aí é geral.

Imagino que nem percebe que está misturando código C com C++. Pode, funciona, mas não é desejável, se souber o que está fazendo, ok, mas em geral as pessoas fazem isto por acidente.

Seria bom ler algumas coisas antes para entender o básico desses conceitos. Pesquise mais no site porque tem outras perguntas feitas que ajudarão entender depois de aprender o básico.

- [O que são e onde estão a "stack" e "heap"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101)
- [Performance de acesso a dados na heap e stack e alocação de objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56580/101)
- [Qual a finalidade da função free()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43766/101)

Este é um dos famosos códigos que funcionam, mas estão errados. A parte boa de fazer em C ou C++ é que dura pouco, rapidinho vai estourar e dar problema, será um pouco tarde demais em alguns casos, mas será tão caótico que a pessoa vai ter que arrumar. Na verdade quase todo mundo desiste dessas linguagens depois de passar esse aperto e opta por linguagens que os erros não causam tanto problema. Algumas linguagens deixam funcionar até coisas erradas por quase todo tempo e isto é suficiente para muitas pessoas. Aqui estou te dando a dica para evitar esse caminho, mas sei que a maioria ignora e continua preferindo só ver funcionando.

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

No caso todas alocações estão no *stack*. Variáveis locais e parâmetros que não deixam de ser variáveis locais.

> ```
> int *p[10];// declara um vetor ponterio para 10 inteiros
> ```

Isto está errado. Está declarando um vetor de 10 posições com ponteiros para inteiros (esses ponteiros devem apontar para inteiros)

> ```
> cout<< *p[0]<<endl; // mostra p[0] primeiro valor da primeira posiçao do vetor de ponteiros
> ```

Isto está confuso. Está mostrando o valor apontado pela primeira posição do vetor `p`.

> ```
> cout<< *p[0]<<"**"<<endl; // o valor agr é 47, pq ?
> ```

Porque sempre que passa algo por referência, e um vetor sempre é uma referência (um [ponteiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101)), não está passando o objeto, não está copiando aquele conteúdo, está copiando o ponteiro que aponta para o objeto real, então tudo o que fizer na outra função vai refletir no objeto original porque tanto aqui quanto lá está apontando para o mesmo objeto, então fica óbvio que uma mudança em algum elemento dele não importa onde aconteceu a mudança será feito no objeto apontado, qualquer lugar que acessar esse objeto terá os mesmos dados. Por isso dizemos que ele é um objeto mutável, diferente de um inteiro isolado por exemplo que é imutável e, por valor e o objeto sempre é copiado se tornando outro objeto em cada uso diferente.

> ```
>  i[0] = &p;/*passa o emdereço do interio "p" criado na heap para o vetor de interios*/
> ```

Aqui é o erro que eu falei. Está guardando no vetor um ponteiro para o valor anteriormente declarado no *stack*. Como você deve ter aprendido, ao final da execução da função as [**variáveis**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) do *stack* deixam de existir. Mas é a variável que deixa de existir, não o objeto, acabou o [tempo de vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) deles, mas n]ao há uma destruíção. Claro, se a variável não aponta mais para ele não considere seguro continuar acessando-o, a qualquer momento ele poderá deixar de existir já que ele não é mais necessário. Ali poderá ser substituído por outro valor, pode ser colocado outro objeto no seu lugar. Na verdade na primeira chamada de função que tenha variáveis locais que atribuírem valor para elas sobrescreverá ali em cima mesmo onde estava esse objeto (isso depende um pouco de alguns fatores, não é tão simples porque depende da implementação).

Como você não chamou nenhuma outra função que estragou seu objeto está funcionando, mas isso é uma coincidência, não conte com isso.

Se deseja que o objeto sobreviva ao fim da função uma das formas é colocá-lo no *heap*, e aí o gerenciamento do tempo de vida dele é determinado por você. Em C++ arcaico aloca-se com `new` e remove com `delete` com o era com `malloc()` e `free()` em C. Mas hoje em C++ se faz de forma bem diferente, mais segura e automática. Esses operadores viraram praticamente detalhe de implementação em quase todos cenários de código moderno.

Tudo isso não é obrigatório em C ou C++, mas é assim que todas implementações funcionam.

Na verdade esse código tem vários erros e nem compila então tudo isso é teórico. Eu refiz o código demonstrando o que está falando:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Test2(int *i) {
    int p = 147;
    i = &p;
}

int main() {
    int *p[10];
    int num = 10;
    p[0] = &num;
    cout << *p[0] << endl;
    Test2(p[0]);
    cout << *p[0] << endl;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/SMpgXo). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/PhantomStackc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/PhantomStack.c).

Comment: Excelente resposta, mas então apesar de funcionar quando chamo o "Cout<< *[0] ; mostrar o 47 mas pode da mer...