# O loop de escolha precisa encerrar ou continuar em um menu

Tags: c++, comparação

Disponho de dois objetos que recebem parâmetros pela entrada padrão do sistema, porem na hora do usuário escolher em continuar ou sair, o *loop* não obedece a saída e quando obedece a saída não obedece o continuar, vou deixar a parte do código, fora das classes pois não é relevante para o problema:

```
#include "setter,getter.h"

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{

  char str;
  int ob1;
  int ob2;
  cout << "selecione a opcao do objeto 1:";
  cin >> ob1;
  cout << "selecione a opcao do objeto 2:";
  cin >> ob2;

  apc *obj1 = new apc(ob1);
  apc *obj2 = new apc(ob2);

  cout << obj1->getPublicInt() << "\n";
  cout << obj1->getPublicStrings() << "\n";

  cout << obj2->getPublicInt() << "\n";
  cout << obj2->getPublicStrings() << "\n";

  while (1)
  {
    cout << "continuar ? s ou n"
         << "\n";
    cin >> str;
    
    if (str = 's' or 'S')
    {
      main();
    }
    if (str = 'n' or 'N')
    {
      system("pause");
      return 0;
    }
    else
    {
      cout << "opcao invalida!";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Acho que quer isto:

```
int main() {
    while (1) {
        char str;
        cout << "selecione a opcao do objeto 1:";
        cin >> ob1;
        cout << "selecione a opcao do objeto 2:";
        cin >> ob2;
        int apc *obj1 = new apc(ob1);
        int apc *obj2 = new apc(ob2);
        cout << obj1->getPublicInt() << "\n";
        cout << obj1->getPublicStrings() << "\n";
        cout << obj2->getPublicInt() << "\n";
        cout << obj2->getPublicStrings() << "\n";
        while (1) {
            cout << "continuar ? s ou n" << "\n";
            cin >> str;
            if (str == 's' || str == 'S') break;
            if (str == 'n' || str == 'N') {
                system("pause");
                return 0;
            } else cout << "opcao invalida!";
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Algorithm/GetData.cpp).

Não chame a função de novo, isso cria recursividade e pode em casos mais extremos quebrar a aplicação, mesmo que funcione em exercício, aprenderá errado, faço um laço que repita a operação, como já sabe fazer.

O laço que ficará mais interno é só para garantir que a pessoa digitou algo válido, então se ele digitou inválido continua no *loop* interno, caso contrário sai. Se for para continuar digitando, só sai de laço e fica dentro do outro mantendo a repetição do laço mais externo, e isso se faz com um `break`. Se é pra sair de vez o `return` funciona bem porque ele sairá dos dois laços.

Havia erro na comparação do texto, o operador correto é o de igualdade `==` e não o de atribuição `=`. E ainda tem que fazer a comparação por completo, quando monta uma expressão só com `'S'` ela é sempre verdadeira, apenas a expressão `str == 'S'` pode dar verdadeira ou falso de acordo com o valor da variável, o compilador não adivinha o que você quer fazer ali, você é responsável por escrever o código certo. E não use `or`, use `||`.

Em exercício não dá problema mas está errado alocar memória e não desalocar como fez, precisa de um `delete`. Veja [Qual a finalidade da função free()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43766/101).

Ningu´-em liga pra isso mas eu vou falar assim mesmo: antes de fazer algum código um pouco mais elaborado, aprenda a sintaxe básica, como a linguagem é, os conceitos de programação, se treinar o erro, é isso que sempre fará. A maioria das pessoas hoje em dia fazem isso e erram muito.

E

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

Comment: kkkkkkkk, ajudou bastante, eu sabia que  era possível de ser feito esse laço assim, mas n passou por minha cabeça, a questão do operar o if com atribuição, foi nas minhas falhas tentativas de identificar o erro, mas depois que eu vi que não era, voltei para a comparação, ainda nao consegui compreender porque de duas comparações terem que ser feitas, acabei esquecendo desses conceitos, e o or, sabia que não podia ser usado, mas o porque não deve ser usado ?

Comment: È considerado obsoleto.