# Como faço para retornar uma string de uma função do tipo char? O valor retornado está sendo NULL

Tags: c, string, ponteiro, char

Estou tendo problemas com a criação de uma função do tipo char que retorna uma string digitada pelo usuário. Eu chamo ela em um método de cadastro e tento jogar para a variável da struct.

```
cadastrarLocacaoNome();
 strcpy(inserir.nomeCliente, cadastrarLocacaoNome());
```

Eu já printeio valor retornado pela função e está dando NULL, segue abaixo a forma que escrevi ela:

```
char cadastrarLocacaoNome(){
    char nomeCliente[100];
    printf ("Informe o nome do cliente\n");
    fflush (stdin);
    fgets (nomeCliente, 100, stdin);
    return nomeCliente[100];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma `string` em `C` é um array de caracteres, um vetor, terminado com `\0`. Quando vamos manipular uma `string`, usamos seu endereço de memória, então para retornar uma `string` precisamos retornar o endereço de memória do primeiro elemento. No seu código você está retornando apenas um `char`, isto é, um único caractere. Oberserve:

```
/* Essa funcao retorna um unico caractere */
char cadastrarLocacaoNome(){
```

Para retornar uma `string` precisamos retornar o endereço do primeiro elemento, se estamos retornando um `endereço`, então a função deve retornar um `ponteiro`. Mas se precisamos de uma `string` por que retornamos um `ponteiro`? Porque um `ponteiro` pode se comportar como um `array`. Há duas pergunta sobre isso: [Arrays são ponteiros?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91336/arrays-s%c3%a3o-ponteiros) e [ponteiro para vetor vs ponteiro para variavel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/193507/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-ponteiro-para-vetor-e-ponteiro-para-vari%c3%a1vel).

Então sua função deveria ser assim:

```
/* Agora essa funcao retorna um ponteiro de char */
char* cadastrarLocacaoNome(){
```

Agora sua função retorna um ponteiro, então temos que alterar isso:

```
/* Outro problema aqui eh que a posicao 100 nao faz parte do seu vetor */
return nomeCliente[100];
```

Para o endereço da primeira posicao do seu vetor, ficando assim:

```
return &nomeCliente[0];
/* Essa forma abaixo equivale como a primeira posicao do vetor */
return nomeCliente;
```

Outro problema no seu código é sobre o [tempo de vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/135572/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-escopo-e-tempo-de-vida) de `char nomeCliente[100];`. Esse vetor só existe na sua função, quando se faz o `return`, o tempo de vida dele acaba.

Quando `strcpy` for chamada, é necessário que a variável `nomeCliente` ainda esteja "viva". Para que isso ocorra podemos declarar o vetor fora da função, mas com isso não haveria necessidade de retornar uma string. Outra solução é utilizar alocação de memória, onde a variável ficará no [heap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3797/o-que-s%c3%a3o-e-onde-est%c3%a3o-a-stack-e-heap) e com isso seu tempo de vida poderá ser controlado. Em `C` podemos usar [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) para alocar memória e [free](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/) para liberar a memória alocada por `malloc`.

Então no seu programa ficaria assim:

```
char* cadastrarLocacaoNome(void) {
    /* Alocando 100 bytes para esse ponteiro, assim podemos usa-lo
       como se fosse um vetor */
    char *nomeCliente = malloc(sizeof *nomeCliente * 100);

    /* Se o ponteiro for NULL entao houve algum erro */
    if (nomeCliente != NULL) {
        /* Aqui eh ativado caso a alocacao seja bem sucedida */
        printf("Informe o nome do cliente: ");
        fgets(nomeCliente, 100, stdin);
    }

    /* Retornando o endereco alocado que tem a string lida ou
    NULL - em case de erro */
    return nomeCliente;
}
```

Agora é só utilizar o retorno da função como se fosse uma string. Um detalhe é que não se deve fazer isso:

```
strcpy(nome, cadastrarLocacaoNome());
```

Pois o endereço retornado (string) precisa ser liberado com o `free`. Veja: [Qual a finalidade da função free?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43766/qual-a-finalidade-da-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-free). Então podemos utilizar uma variável auxiliar, dessa forma:

```
char nome[100];
/* Coloando a string no ponteiro auxiliar */
char *auxiliar = cadastrarLocacaoNome();

/* A funcao retorna NULL em caso de erro na alocacao */
if (auxiliar == NULL) {
    puts("Erro ao alocar memoria!");
    return 1;
}

/* Copiando a string */
strcpy(nome, auxiliar);

/* Liberando a memoria alocada */
free(auxiliar);

printf("Nome: %s", nome);
```

Veja o código funcionando [aqui](https://ideone.com/iSJXY4)